# Centered Image in a TextView

Tags: android, html, css

I want to create a TextView with some images in the middle of the block of text. I accomplished this by using

```
Html.fromHtml(String source, Html.ImageGetter imageGetter, Html.TagHandler tagHandler)
```

and using my own overidden `getDrawable()` method:

```
@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(String source){
     int id;
     if (source.equals("image.png")) {
         id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
     } else {
         return null;
     }
     LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
     Drawable empty = getResources()
             .getDrawable(id);
     d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
     d.setBounds(0, 0,
             empty.getIntrinsicWidth(),
             empty.getIntrinsicHeight());
     return d;
}
```

to replace `<img>` tags. However, the bottom edge of the images I load are always aligned with the bottom of the text like so:

[image]

**My question is: is there a way to vertically center these images?**

The HTML source I used is:

```
title = Html.fromHtml("<img src=\"image.png\" align=\"middle\"/>", this, null);
desc = Html.fromHtml("Text <img src=\"image.png\" align=\"middle\"/> "
                + "text <img src=\"image.png\" align=\"middle\"/> blah blah blah blah blah<br>"
                + "Blah <img src=\"image.png\" align=\"middle\"/> blah blah", this, null);
```

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer to this in 2021, I recommend constructing your own view instead. It is more flexible and will actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `line-height` of the text to the height of the image.  This will make the space used by the text as tall as the image and should vertically center the text.

I'm not sure how exactly to implement this the way you are generating your html, but you can try something like this to add the css:

```
desc = Html.fromHtml("<div style=\"line-height: 60px;\">Text <img src=\"image.png\" align=\"middle\"/> "
            + "text <img src=\"image.png\" align=\"middle\"/> blah blah blah blah blah<br>"
            + "Blah <img src=\"image.png\" align=\"middle\"/> blah blah</div>", this, null);
```

Of course you will want to change the 60px to the height of your image

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
desc = Html.fromHtml("Text <img src=\"image.png\"  style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" /> "
+ "text <img src=\"image.png\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" /> blah blah blah blah blah<br>"
+ "Blah <img src=\"image.png\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" /> blah blah", this, null);
```

This may be solve your problem.